# sql server 2008 instead of trigger programatically decide whether to run or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Is it possible to programatically decide whether a INSTEAD OF trigger can run or not?  What I'd like is some code like this inside the trigger...

```
If (some condition = true) then
       handle the INSTEAD OF trigger code
else
       return // let the insert/update/delete operation happen normally
```

Is that possible inside SQL Server 2008?

**UPDATE:**  Let me clarify my question.  I know you can run conditional statements inside of triggers.  However, as I understand it, if you run the INSTEAD OF trigger then there's no way the regular insert/update/delete operation will ever be possible to run.  I'd like the best of both worlds, if possible.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific. Do you want to be able to pass a value to a trigger or just have some logic inside there? The answers of which are yes and no.

Comment: No this is not possible. The trigger will always run if defined. Though obviously you can have conditional logic to just perform the normal insert you cannot skip the trigger and you will still get the trigger overhead of setting up the inserted/deleted pseudo tables.

Comment: just to clarify I typed the yes and no the wrong way round. You cannot pass a value to a trigger but you can have conditional logic inside one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a conditional statement inside a trigger.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214456(v=sql.80).aspx